# What's the easiest way to tail a file in a Windows machine remotely?

Tags: windows, logging, remote-access, tail

I have a windows server where there is growing log file. I would like to tail this file remotely without having to log in to the server. What are the available options and what would be the recommended method to do this?

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to list the tail of a file similar to tail -f using powershell

cat  -Tail 10 -Wait

Path to the file this can be unc to the admin share i.e. \server01\c$\logs\logfile.log

cat is an alias for powershells get-content

-Tail 
the number after tail is the number of line to list

-Wait 
tells powershell to wait for more lines to be added to the log file